# Graphic Quality in PowerPoint graphics export

Tags: vba, png, powerpoint

I have some difficulties with exporting graphics in PowerPoint as images.

When I export a graphic from powerpoint manually (Rightclick -> Save as Picture) the image has a much better quality than when exported using VBA:

```
Call objPPTshape.Export(strExportName, ppSaveAsPNG)
```

Can someone explain why this problem occurs?

I use this workaround to save some print areas from an excel worksheet to png files. Is there an easier way to export high quality pngs from excel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add some parameters after your call, you should get better results:

```
objPPTshape.Export strExportName, ppSaveAsPNG, 1000, 1000, ppRelativeToSlide
```

Tweak the numbers as needed.
No need for Call ( ) - just call methods with their name and no brackets

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot. Didn't know that passing parameters works with the Export-Function.

Comment: Do you also have advice which parameters to pass in the method?
When I pass shape.width and shape.height the image does not have the right aspect ratio

Comment: It seems as if it is an undocumented method. The last parameter have four possible values: ppRelativeToSlide, ppClipRelativeToSlide, ppScaleToFit, ppScaleXY. The two numbers - no clue - twips perhaps?

Comment: I did some research on this:
The size parameters (first: width, second: height) are scaled by a factor:
Width is scaled by **1.171** (so 1000 width results in 1171px width in png). Height is scaled by **0.863** making 863px in PNG out of 1000 passed to the method.

Max width that I was able to create is (3070px in PNG, 2621 in VBA). If exceeding this value, the image is simply cut off.

Changing the export method (ppRelativeToSlide etc.) did not change anything in the result.

Comment: Graphics quality still isnt equally good as manually saving the picture. So if there is any other idea how to get the same result I would be happy.